# How to make the selected testcript is run in selenium grid

Tags: selenium-grid

I need a help.........

I can launch some remote control by using: 
ant launch-remote-control

but I dont know how my script connect to hub?
I set up ant, selenium-grid on the same computer.
I have an grid.dll which is written by C# and run through NUnit.
The test data is read from xml file (ValidData.xml)
The example code is below :

using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System;
using System.Xml;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading;
using NUnit.Framework;
using Selenium;

namespace Grid
{
    public class Class1
    {
        //User defined

```
    private string strURL = "http://gmail.com/";
    private string[] strBrowser = new string[3] { "*iehta", "*firefox", "*safari" };
   string hubAddress = "192.168.20.131"; // IP of my computer

    // System defined
    private ISelenium selenium;
    private StringBuilder verificationErrors;

    [SetUp]
    public void SetupTest()
    {

        selenium = new DefaultSelenium(hubAddress, 4444, this.strBrowser[1], this.strURL);// do i need to identify browser when I defined it when launching a remote control
        selenium.Start();
        verificationErrors = new StringBuilder();
    }

    [TearDown]
    public void TeardownTest()
    {
        try
        {
            selenium.Stop();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // Ignore errors if unable to close the browser
        }
        Assert.AreEqual("", verificationErrors.ToString());
    }

    private string[] name;

    [Test]
    public void LoginPassedTest()
    {
        try
        {
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            XmlNode docNode;

            doc.Load("ValidData.xml");
            docNode = doc["TestCase"];

            foreach (XmlNode node in docNode)
            {
                selenium.Open("/");
                selenium.WaitForPageToLoad("50000");
                selenium.Type("Email", node["username"].InnerText);
                selenium.Type("Passwd", node["password"].InnerText);
                selenium.Click("signIn");
                selenium.WaitForPageToLoad("100000");
                name = (selenium.GetText("//div[@id='guser']/nobr/b").Split('@'));

                try
                {
                    Assert.AreEqual(node["username"].InnerText, name[0]);
                    Assert.AreEqual("Sign out", selenium.GetText(":r6"));
                }
                catch (AssertionException e)
                {
                    verificationErrors.Append(e.Message);
                }

                selenium.Click(":r6");
            }
        }
        catch (AssertionException e)
        {
            verificationErrors.Append(e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Step I run this script:
1.I build that script into DLL
2.I start hub by using command "ant lauch-hub"
3.I start 2 remote controls by using command :
      ant -Dport=5566 -Denvironment="*chrome" launch-remote-control
      ant -Dport=5577 -Denvironment="*iexplore" launch-remote-control
4.Then I open Nunit and load DLL (code above) and run
5.The NUNit doesnot respond anything.

I think there are some missing things but I dont know.
How can the test script (DLL) know which is sequence of remote control is selected to run the test????

Please help me!!
Thank you so much

Yui.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see [TestFixture] attribute for Class1. May be that is the problem?

I described procedure of executing tests on selenium grid here: http://slmoloch.blogspot.com/2009/12/design-of-selenium-tests-for-aspnet_19.html. and  you can download sources of tests here: http://code.google.com/p/design-of-selenium-tests-for-asp-net/